# Datagrid row not being read code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code...

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
     Dim SocioNumInfo As Integer = CInt(GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedIndex).Cells(4).Text)
     MsgBox(SocioNumInfo.ToString)
     ...
 End Sub
```

Now, this code should read the cell, but it gives me the following error:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

The MsgBox is just there for me to check if the data is being read, at the end of the day it should turn that into a parameter so I can add to the DB... but still.. nope nothing. Is that the correct code to read directly from a cell in a choosen row? In the "Protected Sub" area I already tried SelectedIndexChanging and RowEditing, etc... and still nothing. Still throws the error at me.

If I try
`Dim SocioNumInfo As String = CStr(GridView1.Rows(GridView1.SelectedRow).Cells(4).Text)` it gives me a "cannot be converted to Integer" error.

Comment: indexing is zero based. so are you accessing the right cell ?

Comment: How many cells are there?  I'm guessing fewer than 5?  (Keep in mind that indexing the `Cells` collection here is zero-based, so if you're looking for the fourth cell it would be `3`.  Keep in mind also that `RowUpdating` may potentially be fired for a header row or a footer row as well, which might only have 1 cell.)

Comment: I was counting the cell that .Net makes for adding its labels, for example the EDIT label, and I ended up with (2). It still throws me the same error. Not really sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If I add a "Enable Selection" option which shows the "SELECT" label in the Datagrid, if I click Select and and then Edit it shows the MessageBox as being empty. Of course this isn't ideal as the ideal thing would be to just click Edit and the MessageBox should show the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no row is selected then `GridView1.SelectedIndex` is `-1`. You might have to add a check

```
If GridView1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
    ' Use GridView1.SelectedIndex here
End If
```

However, it is easier to access the selected row like this:

```
Dim row = GridView1.SelectedRow
If Not row Is Nothing AndAlso IsNumeric(row.Cells(2).Text) Then
    Dim SocioNumInfo As Integer = CInt(row.Cells(2).Text)
    ....        
End If
```

Note that the cell index is zero based. `row.Cells(4)` is in the 5th column.

Comment: Hello Oliver, thanks a lot for the reply. Its still throwing me an error....
`Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged Dim row = GridView1.SelectedRow
        If Not row Is Nothing Then
            Dim SocioNumInfo As Integer = CInt(row.Cells(2).Text)
            MsgBox(SocioNumInfo.ToString)
        End If`

Comment: Still not displaying and if i select Edit directly it still thows me the 
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index " error. My head is blowing smoke right now, heh.

Comment: Nevermind, adjusted the code accordingly. It was entirely my bad. Thanks a million Oliver :)

Comment: You could also check if `row.Cells(2).Text` is really numeric. `If IsNumeric(row.Cells(2).Text) Then ...`.